# Смена имени hostname в Linux

Tags: linux, systemd

Почему после выполенния команды `hostnamectl set-hostname new-name` - терминал открываеться через раз (при нажатие горячих клавиш открытия терминала). Linux же не обязательно перезагружать после правок. После перезагрузки системы открытие терминала нормализуется).

Comment: Какой линукс, какой терминал, какая горячая клавиша? // «Линукс же не обязательно перезагружать после правок» — это неправда, вас обманули

Comment: правка правке рознь, порой достаточно перезагрузить какую нибудь связанную службу.

Comment: @andreymal, если это неправда, то у вас не Linux.

Comment: @0andriy окей, как внести и применить изменения в, например, /proc/cmdline без перезагрузки?

Comment: @andreymal после загрузки оно и не используется ни разу. давайте пример который влияет на рантайм)

Comment: @eri вот именно поэтому линукс придётся обязательно перезагружать после правки cmdline — чтоб изменения повлияли на рантайм

Comment: @andreymal там ничего полезного нет и что-то там нужно менять наверное раз в жизнь. `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=UUID=bc8fe406-72f6-4017-8f7d-047ae7673819 rw loglevel=3 quiet amd_iommu=on iommu=pt`

Comment: @eri ну перезагружать-то после изменений всё придётся) Упомянутый в вопросе hostname, кстати, тоже обычно не приходится менять чаще раза в жизнь

Comment: @user490822 как именно настроенны горячие клавиши? как воспроизвести проблему на чистой системе?

Comment: у вас скорее всего проблема возникает на уровне DE(Desktop environment - Среда рабочего стола) которую кстати вы так и не озвучили. Я например использую связку archlinux+sway+alacritty и никаких проблем с динамической сменой hostname не возникает. Попробуйте вместо полной перезагрузки просто перезайти пользователем.

Comment: @andreymal, для большинства параметров, которые используются в дистрибутивах, отсутствие перезагрузки не критично — ну поживёт ещё какое-то время. Да и вообще, для экспериментов есть виртуальные машины, или вы на продуктовом сервере настройки меняете каждый день?!

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтоб имя хоста применилось к пользовательской сессии нужно загрузить новые переменные окружения. Проще всего это сделать перезапустив сессию.

Comment: Ну а почему «терминал открываеться через раз»?

Comment: @andreymal в вопросе вообще нет вопроса, поэтому как мне сказали на экзамене по информатике "задай себе вопрос сам, блестяще ответь на него и вали уже отсюда" а не открывается скорее всего из-за особенностей ipc. может dbus не сигналит

Comment: @andreymal, скорее всего пытается отрезольвить новый адрес. Один раз попадает на старый, один раз на новый.